# Keep Nuget package always use latest dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

To be clear, I have published a package called A.1.0.0.nupkg.

A.1.0.0.nupkg have some dependencies:
B.1.0.0.nupkg,
C.1.0.0.nupkg,
D.1.0.0.nupkg.
All have been published.

In A.csproj, I wrote

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="B" Version="1.0.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="C" Version="1.0.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="D" Version="1.0.*" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Now B has some updates, and upgrade to 1.0.1. And I upload it to NuGet.

How to keep A always use the latest dependencies automatically, without recompile A?

Comment: Seems https://stackoverflow.com/q/46486983/7068790 has the same issue. But setting `-DependencyVersion Highest` not working now.

Answer (score 0):

You're using floating versions - unfortunately it seems these aren't supported for NuGet packages, only for the projects that reference them. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56889368/2066474

So if you have a project which references `A` and you want it to also use the latest patch version of `B` then your project will need something like this

```
<ItemGroup> 
  <PackageReference Include="A" Version="1.0.1" /> 
  <PackageReference Include="B" Version="1.0.*" />
</ItemGroup>
```